# Error from logistic regression Zelig R

Tags: r

I'm running a logit model using the zelig package in R.

```
m3 <- zelig (newdata$bes.Turnout ~  civicduty + newdata$bes.CivicDuty2+newdata$bes.Age, model="logit", data=newdata)
```

`newdata$bes.Turnout` is binary, the rest are numerical.

I try to set the values of x.

```
mcos<- median(newdata$bes.CivicDuty2)
civicmean<-mean(civicduty)  
mage<-mean(newdata$bes.Age)

test<-setx(m3, civicduty=civicmean, newdata$bes.CivicDuty2=mcos, newdata$bes.Age=mage)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "test<-setx(m3, civicduty=civicmean, newdata$bes.CivicDuty2="
```

I have tried the same code for the survival data in Zelig, and here the setx worked.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That call to `setx` doesn't make sense to me. My best guess is that you want something like

```
test<-setx(m3, 
           civicduty = mean(newdata$civicduty),
           bes.CivicDuty2 = mean(newdata$bes.CivicDuty2,
           bes.Age = mean(newdata$bes.Age))
```